# Pass argument to Doctrine's lifecycle callback method

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine-orm

I have Doctrine entity `File` which knows relative path to file on disk (e.g. `m/d/5/md5.flac`). Since I don't wanna have disk full of useless files I would like to remove file from disk as well.

For this purpose I decided **to take advantage of Doctrine's lifecycle callbacks** because they are really simple to use. The problem is I don't have first part of absolute path (e.g. `/mnt/storage`) to file which is configured in my `config.yml` as one of many options.

Is there any way **how can I pass config option to lifecycle callback**?

The other possibility I found is to use normal doctrine event but it seems to be an overkill to call one `unlink()`.

Comment: IMHO having a normal [entity listener](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners), that is registered in DIC to allow constructor argument configuration is a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [symfony/doctrine documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html):

> Lifecycle callbacks method receives no arguments. This is always the
>   case for lifecycle callbacks and is intentional: lifecycle callbacks
>   should be simple methods that are concerned with internally
>   transforming data in the entity (e.g. setting a created/updated field,
>   generating a slug value).

I think that best option in this case is to set the path of the file you want to process/remove and do the processing in the callback method for your entity.

Comment: Why there is everything on Symfony's documentation and Google never find it? I feel bad. Anyway, adding full path to the entity's path will be future nightmare. It does not allow me to easily move upload path to another service - like AWS E3. Do you think I should use normal doctrine events for this purpose? Those are registered as tagged services so I can pas any arguments using DI I guess.

Comment: You can use a predefined location to manage the files and determine the path based on attributes of your entity, like an id, that could simplify things a little bit.

Comment: Entity knows its relative path. I can call ``unlink($this->getRelativePath())`` which results into deletiong of ``a/b/c/abc.jpg``. The entity does not have base path (``/mnt/x``) though. It would be weird to set the base path before deleting (I don't see other option here). I think **Doctrine Events** are the only solution here because **I can autowire** ``%upload.basePath%`` in any service using **Symfony's DI**.